# EF Core tracking problem when adding Entity to a List

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I ran into a problem while developing my small Blazor WASM app.
A part of my app is where users can create teams, and invite other users to join their team. The relevant Entity Classes is:

`Team.cs`

```
public class Team
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid TeamID { get; set; }        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
        public Guid? BadgeID { get; set; }
        public Guid TownID { get; set; }
        public Guid StatisticsID { get; set; }
        public Guid CaptainID { get; set; }
        public List<AppUserDTO> Players { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

When a User accepts an invitation he should be added to the `List<AppUserDTO> Players` List, I do this this way on the client side:

```
private async Task AcceptInvite()
{
      Team.Players.Add(Player);
      await TeamDataService.UpdateTeam(Team);
}
```

```
public async Task UpdateTeam(Team team)
{
    var teamJson =
          new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(team), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    await _httpClient.PutAsync("api/team", teamJson);
}
```

But I get the following exception on the server side when I'd like to save the changes to the server:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'AppUserDTO' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

With the server-side code being:

```
 public Team UpdateTeam(Team team)
{
       var updatedTeam = _appDbContext.Teams.Include(t => t.Players).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamID == team.TeamID);

       if (updatedTeam == null) return null;

       updatedTeam.TeamID = team.TeamID;
       updatedTeam.Name = team.Name;
       updatedTeam.Abbreviation = team.Abbreviation;
       updatedTeam.TownID = team.TownID;
       updatedTeam.StatisticsID = team.StatisticsID;
       updatedTeam.Players = team.Players;
       updatedTeam.CaptainID = team.CaptainID;

       _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
       return updatedTeam;
}
```

The exception pops up at the _appDbContext.SaveChanges() method.

What I noticed is the following: When I add an Entity to an empty list and save it, I get no exception, but if the list already has Entities I get this error.

What would be the solution for this, I believe is quite common what I try to do, but I didn't find a solution anywhere for this.

Comment: Maybe `updatedTeam.Players.AddRange(team.Players)` ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv same exception. In my mind it doesn't make sense what you suggested, because updatedTeam will already have some players, while team will have the same players + 1, which is about to join.

Comment: Strange here, why `Team` has `AppUserDTO` classes. DTO should be not a part of DB Model.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
var updatedTeam = _appDbContext.Teams
   ..Include(t => t.Players).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamID == team.TeamID);
```

... you are retrieving existing Players from the Db and _appDbContext is tracking them (by "ID").

Now, when you set Players:

```
  updatedTeam.Players = team.Players;
```

... I suspect that team.Players includes Players that are already being tracked by the _appDbContext.  Hence your error.

You could try:

```
List<Player> playersToAdd = team.Players.Except(updatedTeam.Players);
updatedTeam.AddRange(playersToAdd);
```

In this way, you are not adding duplicate players to the context that are already being tracked from the initial database retrieval.